# Generate a image which produces gif like effect

Tags: python, django, apache

I am trying to generate a image which produces gif like effect by flushing the response continuously to the browser, I am relatively new to django/python and tried with following code testing for both text and image. The generator for text works fine but in case of image only first version of image is being generated.

I tried searching but can't find anything on this. I am confused how to proceed with this or if this is at all possible with django or If the idea is conceptually wrong.

**Image Generator :**

```
def refreshx():
    from PIL import Image
    from PIL import ImageFont
    from PIL import ImageDraw 

    size = (1000,500)            
    im = Image.new('RGB', size) 
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)   

    red = (255,255,255)    
    text_pos = (10,30) 
    draw.text(text_pos, str(datetime.datetime.today()), fill=red)


    buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
    im.save(buffer, 'PNG')
    yield buffer.getvalue()

    time.sleep(5)
    buffers = StringIO.StringIO()

    ims = Image.new('RGB', size) 
    draws = ImageDraw.Draw(ims)
    text_poss = (30,80)
    draws.text(text_poss, 'dasdasdsa', fill=red)    
    print 'been there'
    ims.save(buffers, 'PNG')
    yield buffers.getvalue()
```

**Text Generator :**

```
def testgenerator():
    yield str(datetime.datetime.today())
    time.sleep(5)
    yield str(datetime.datetime.today())
```

**View Function :**

```
def test(request):
    #return HttpResponse(testgenerator());
    return HttpResponse(refreshx(), mimetype="image/png")
```

EDIT :

I learned while researching that there's a concept called **gifsocket**, I'm looking into it..please suggest if anyone has experience with these